# convert 5.1 PRORES to Prores stereo

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to extract a prores video with just 2.0 (with L R on same track) from a Prores with the below audio track layout. How can I do that using the FFmpeg library?

I could not figure out which command to use from the below ffmpeg library spec https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#a2monostereo

Desired Output PRORES to contain below track layout

track 0 - video (src Stream #0:0)
track 1 - L R (src Stream #0:1)

Below is the source video/audio Track Layout

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (HQ) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 171944 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23976 tbn, 23976 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
  handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
  encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 HQ
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FL), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
  handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FR), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
  handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
  handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (LFE), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
  handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (BL), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
  handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (BR), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
  handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
Stream #0:7(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, downmix, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
  handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
Stream #0:8(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2020-03-17T19:58:52.000000Z
  handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
  reel_name       :
  timecode        : 00:00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to extract the first two audio tracks as a single stereo track, use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -filter_complex "[0:a:0][0:a:1]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo" -c:v copy out.mov
```

If you wish to copy the existing downmix track (#0:7), use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -map 0:v -map 0:7 -c copy out.mov
```

Comment: Thank you!    how can we map the video on track1 and audio on track2 and also the audio label to be `L R` ?

Comment: The order of the `-map` options determines their order in the output. I'm not clear by what you mean by label?

Comment: 1. I ran this command to make sure video is track1 and audio (L R) on track2

 ffmpeg -i samplemulti.mov -filter_complex "[0:a:0][0:a:1]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo" -c:v -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy 20_out_03.mov

Comment: 2. The converted file ffprobe is showing as LC but I wanted the label to be L R

  screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQCc7.png

Comment: LC here represents the codec profile. It stands for Low Complexity. The channel layout is to the right - "stereo". Stereo is always Left + Right. Any other configuration will be shown as "2.0 channels".

Comment: understood on  LC

can you advise on below?

 I ran this command to make sure video is track1 and audio (L R) on track2, it did not work...

ffmpeg -i samplemulti.mov -filter_complex "[0:a:0][0:a:1]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo" -c:v -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy 20_out_03.mov

Comment: Outputs from filtergraphs should be labelled and then mapped in order to ensure order. `ffmpeg -i samplemulti.mov -filter_complex "[0:a:0][0:a:1]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy 20_out_03.mov`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231561/discussion-between-user2920456-and-gyan).